# Annoying VDPAU error in MPlayer

Tags: nvidia, mplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GNOME Mplayer: “Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13487/gnome-mplayer-failed-to-open-vdpau-backend-libvdpau-nvidia-so-error)

Every time I play a video with MPlayer, I'm getting an annoying popup dialog saying:

> Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to solve this? My laptop is A Compaq CQ20-213TU.

Answer (score 0):

Install proprietary nvidia drivers or switch off VDPAU support in mplayer.

EDIT:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall libvdpau1
```

Comment: how? can you teach me? thank you

Comment: Do you have nvidia card, right?

Comment: I think I have no nvdia card because I'm using integrated pre-installed in my laptop.

Comment: i apologize if you don't understand what I am saying because I am still a newbie. hopefully you can help me through

Comment: Do you install mplayer or other software from PPA ? Is your system clean install of Ubuntu?

Comment: how to switch off VDPAU support in mplayer?

Comment: sudo aptitude reinstall libvdpau1 <------- I already paste thie command into terminal but the results -----> sudo: aptitude: command not found

Comment: Another way to reinstall libvdpau1: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libvdpau1`.