# Gnome Mplayer failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so

Tags: 10.10, mplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GNOME Mplayer: “Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13487/gnome-mplayer-failed-to-open-vdpau-backend-libvdpau-nvidia-so-error)

When I open an avi file under Gnome Mplayer, there is an error report:

> Failed to open VDPAU backend
>   libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

I then followed [this blog](http://vsingleton.blogspot.com/2010/02/failed-to-open-vdpau-backend.html) to solve this problem, which suggests two ways.

1. The first way is to call mplayer in
   terminal:

   > mplayer -vo xv video.wmv

   This works for me.
2. But I would like to try the second
   way, which is to call GUI version of Gnome Mplayer by writing some options in
   one of the configure files of Gnome
   Mplayer. I choose to write into
   ~/.mplayer/config, where I wrote:

   > -vo xv

   But it does not work. So I was
   wondering if I make any mistake?
   What to write into the configure
   file?

Thanks and regards!

---

ADDED:

I followed fragos's reply, by replacing the original command "gnome-mplayer %U " with "gnome-mplayer -vo xv %U " in its item in the Applications menu. But this fails to call the Gnome Mplayer. Any idea why? Thanks!