# How to add Open3D app to select application

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, file-format

I have Ubuntu `20.04`, I installed **Open3D** app as debian from [here](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/releases/download/v0.17.0/open3d-app-0.17.0-Ubuntu.deb), but I can't see the app as an option when I try to open the `.obj` files for example. can you please tell me how can I add Open3D to be an option when selecting other apps to open a file in ubuntu? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the "search" icon to find Open3D?

Comment: @stumblebee I did, but didn't find it!

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/491383/1033376) solved my problem, so I flag my question as duplicate.