# how do i install light table?

Tags: python

I am very new to Ubuntu and I plan on learning python for which I need to install light table.
I couldn't find any specific instructions anywhere on the net. please provide me the steps in detail. Also I couldn't find any opt folder in my home directory and most of the websites tell me that's the place I have to copy the extracted light table folder.

Comment: The opt folder is not in home directories, but in /. The path of your home directory looks like `/home/name`, and the path of opt is simply `/opt`. You don't have to extract it to opt. You can simply put it in your home directory and run it from there.

Answer (score 7):

Download the correct version for your system from [lighttable.com](http://www.lighttable.com/).

Change directory to wherever the file is located. By default your browser will place it to your Downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Unzip the archive. This will give you a folder called LightTable.
The wildcard '*' in the filename makes this command work for either the 32-bit or 64-bit downloads.

```
tar xzf LightTableLinux*.tar.gz
rm LightTableLinux*.tar.gz
```

Move the unzipped folder to '/opt'.

```
sudo mv LightTable/ /opt
```

Create a launcher file called 'light-table.desktop'

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/light-table.desktop
```

and put the following on it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Light Table
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/opt/LightTable/LightTable
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/LightTable/core/img/lticon.png
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;Utility;TextEditor;Application;IDE;Development;
```

Finally, create a symlink to enable calling Light Table from a terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/LightTable/LightTable /usr/local/bin/light-table
```

Source: [brandonrubin.me](http://www.brandonrubin.me/2014/06/23/install-light-table-on-ubuntu-with-launcher/)

Comment: How can add LightTable to my Open With... list of programs, for text files?

Comment: @becko see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162612/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-list-of-open-with-applications

Comment: this does not work anymore: sudo ln -s /opt/LightTable/LightTable /usr/local/bin/light-table