# Error while installing Light-Table on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04

I'm trying to install the `LightTable` code editor by downloading the tar file as explained in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498505/how-do-i-install-light-table). However when I try to run the executable, I'm getting the following error

```
./LightTable: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

How can we fix this? Can we install `LightTable` on Ubuntu using `snap` or `apt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned *libgconf-2.so.4* library is contained in [`libgconf-2-4` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgconf-2.so.4). You have to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

Then LightTable will crash with the following message:

> ```
> $ ./LightTable 
>
> (LightTable:2396): Pango-ERROR **: 18:24:23.862: Harfbuzz version too old (1.0.0)
>
> Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
> ```

So you have to use modern fully-functional alternatives as VSCodium or Atom.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that this is indeed the case. I have already tried atom and VScode and I did not like both. I did not like the Pylance add on in particular in VScode, You can click on my profile and see a number of questions I have asked regarding VScode and you will know why I hate VScode.