# How can I edit a LibreOffice Writer template file (.ott) directly?

Tags: libreoffice, templates

I have a certain template file for LO Writer.

How can I edit that file directly, i.e. not by creating a new `.odt` file and saving it as a `.ott` file again?

This question is based on the following experience: under Windows, it is possible to right-click the file and choose something along the lines of **Edit this file**, which then open the `.ott`-file itself instead a blank new document.

Comment: If the LO version under Windows behaves differently it would probably be best ask about this on the LO website http://en.libreofficeforum.org/forum/apps/writer  There probably is a reason for this. Or otherwise file a bug https://bugs.documentfoundation.org//

Answer (score 4):

Like most LibreOffice file formats, the .ott file is just a compressed archive. Rename it to `filename.zip` and open it with the archive manager. You will find several files and folders in it. Most likely you want to edit the `contents.xml` file. When you're done, compress the files and rename the file to `newfilename.ott`. Unless you have made a mistake somewhere, you can open this file with LibreOffice. LibreOffice is not very lenient towards errors in the XML markup, and will refuse to open the file if you forget to close a tag, for instance.

Comment: This does not help. I amended my op to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 4):

LibreOffice supports the [`-o` command line parameter](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/libreoffice.1.html#options) which does exactly this:

```
       -o file...
              Opens the given files for editing, even templates.

              Without -o a template file would create a new document derived from that template.
```

Unfortunately there is no shortcut in the file manager to access this functionality. But I guess you could [add your own `.desktop` file](https://askubuntu.com/a/72539) which does this; or you could [edit](https://askubuntu.com/a/162656) `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop` and manually add the `-o` parameter to the `Exec=` line.

Alternatively you can run `libreoffice -o MyTemplate.ott` command in Terminal to edit the `MyTemplate.ott` file.

Answer (score 3):

Select

1. File -> Templates -> Manage
2. Click on the template of interest.
3. Click the 'Edit' button that appears in step 2).

If your template doesn't appear in the list of templates then you may need to import it.

- File -> Templates -> Manage
- Click the 'Import' button.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is to open the template file you want to edit; this gives you an "Untitled 1" document.

However, you can edit this and save it over the old template file.

It's not as slick as using Microsoft Word on Windows, but it accomplishes essentially the same thing.

Comment: This works but is not intuitive at all. I recall some menu option to "edit as template" or similar, but it seems to have vanished...