# Text editor installed via deb, but not shown in "open with" menu

Tags: deb

I made deb installer. Text editor ok installed. It has category "editors" in deb file. Why it's not shown in "Open with" menu (Ubuntu 14.04)? even in Other applications.

Maybe fix my deb file? (I cannot show it, it beta).

Comment: I am afraid we cannot tell without more information. What does the launcher look like?

Comment: I copy binary file to /usr/bin and copy stuff to /usr/share (in DEB pkg). I have app installed to /usr/bin. I don't create .desktop files yet..

Comment: That should be it, since the mime types are set in the .desktop files, together with the %F after the exec. command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an application to the list of Open With applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162612/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-list-of-open-with-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show an entry in <kbd>open with</kbd>, you need a `desktop` file. In your case in `/usr/share/applications`.

And you need a `%f` or `%F` at the end of the command for `Exec=`

```
Exec variables
Add...  Accepts...
%f      a single filename.
%F      multiple filenames.
%u      a single URL.
%U      multiple URLs.
%d      a single directory. Used in conjunction with %f to locate a file.
%D      multiple directories. Used in conjunction with %F to locate files.
%n      a single filename without a path.
%N      multiple filenames without paths.
%k      a URI or local filename of the location of the desktop file.
%v      the name of the Device entry.
```

---

E.G.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myeditor
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=myeditor %F
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=accessories-text-editor
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
```