# How to open mp4 with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, default-programs, mp4

You know, we can drag the mp4 movie to Chrome to play it.

I want to open it with Chrome as default.

But I can't find google-chrome at the "Other Application", as I can find the Firefox there.

How can I do that, because VLC and Firefox didn't work well with some movie?

Comment: Try playing that movie with SMPlayer. I see no reason why a browser should play a movie in a better fashion than a dedicated video player does.

Comment: Maybe the answer to this other question will help you add Chrome to the "Other Application" menu. http://askubuntu.com/a/359963/146105

Comment: @CristianaNicolae Duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change default program to open video files (12.04)?](/questions/158547/how-do-i-change-default-program-to-open-video-files-12-04) – specifically the last paragraph of [atenz' answer](/a/158560/175814)

Comment: @BharadwajRaju - Not sure. The both questions have something in common but they are still different. The answer I've mentioned earlier seems to be a general solution. Anyway, until the user that posted the current question ( @Levi) doesn't add more info and a bit of feedback, we can't know for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an application to the list of Open With applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162612/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-list-of-open-with-applications)

Comment: @CristianaNicolae, Well maybe it's duplicated, but when i add "%F" after Exec, Chrome is still not in the menu.

Comment: @ipselute, I tried the smplayer and it works.  Only smplayer and  Chrome can play it well.  Some frame break in VLC and Firefox

Comment: In that case, it can't be a REAL duplicate, can it? Because the general/generic rule cannot apply in this case. After all, it's not the question that matters the most but it is the answer, the manner to solve the problem. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @levi: Please add an answer if you consider your question as solved.

Answer (score -1):

Rightclick on the ".mp4" file, choose "open with" and then "choose another app". Scroll down to the bottom and choose "more apps", click it. Then scroll down again and click "Look for another app on this PC". This will pop up a file explorer. Go to the directory where You installed Chrome and dubbleclick on "chrome.exe". Default directory of Chrome is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application".