# Adobe Reader application association issue

Tags: 20.04, file-association, adobe-reader, gnome-flashback

I have a few strange PDF files (that I received once from my bank) that open correctly **only** in Adobe Reader. So on my new Ubuntu 20.04 I installed Adobe Reader from the latest available Linux version (AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb) to be able to open these files.
After installation, Adobe Reader set itself as the default application for PDF files, so I set the default application back to Evince. After I did this, Adobe Reader does no more appear in the "Open with another application" menu, so I cannot use it with right-click - I have to open Adobe Reader from the main menu and use File/Open in the application or drag-and-drop. It is a bit inconvenient.

I checked /usr/share/applications/defaults.list (actually a symlink to /etc/gnome/defaults.list) and it contains the line
`application/pdf=AdobeReader.desktop`
which must have been added during Adobe Reader installation. However, my ~/.config/mimeapps.list contains in `[Default Applications]` section the line
`application/pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop`
as I have set the default app back to Evince, and it also contains in `[Added Associations]` the line
`application/pdf=AdobeReader.desktop;`
which I guess should cause Adobe Reader be displayed among applications suitable to open a PDF file - but it isn't.

Even after I manually changed the line in /usr/share/applications/defaults.list to `application/pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop` and removed the same from my ~/.config/mimeapps.list, it didn't change anything. Adobe Reader is still not displayed. I ran `update-desktop-database`, logged out and back in from the DE.

What else can I try?

BTW. I'm using GNOME Flashback, so the file manager is Nautilus.

Comment: Did you see https://askubuntu.com/questions/162612/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-list-of-open-with-applications?

Comment: So, lack of %F in AdobeReader.desktop file was the issue. I'd never figure this out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following muktupavels' comment above, i replaced the line `Exec=acroread` with `Exec=acroread %F` in `/usr/share/applications/AdobeReader.desktop` file and this solved the issue.