# How does application get the file name in case of launch by "open file with"?

Tags: files, process, file-association

For example, Windows starts a new process of the selected application and passes the name of the file to be opened to the process with an additional command line argument (for my app: argv[0] - executable file, argv[1] - openable file).
Ubuntu launches my application, but the process does not receive any additional arguments (only argv[0]). How can my application find out the name of a file that a user opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file manager will pass along the URI of the file that you right-clicked in order to select "Open With".

In linux desktops, applications are launched using a launcher file. A launcher file is a plain text file with the `.desktop` extension. It contains information for the desktop environment on how to start the application, what icon to use, how and where to display it in the menu, etc. The `Open With Other Application" list in Files (nautilus) is populated by the` .desktop` files present on your system.

It is in the `.desktop` file on the `Exec=` line that [arguments are defined](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30210/what-does-u-mean-when-calling-a-command). For example, for the editor Gedit, this line is

```
Exec=gedit %U
```

Only when the `Exec=` entry of the `.desktop` file contains an argument, the system will pass the argument it received from Files (nautilus) to the program.