# "Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so" error even though not using MPlayer

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-classic, mplayer, output

I keep getting the following error message on my terminal:

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I understand this has something to do with GNOME MPlayer, but AFAIK *I'm not using this program at all!*

How can I fix whatever it is that is causing these messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify the process that's sending error messages to terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/314231) This looks like [bug 1300215](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvdpau/+bug/1300215), which affects more than just MPlayer. [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/13487) (linked [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/314238)) regards MPlayer but [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/71586) may help. Yet, rather than being duped to that or closed as a "bug report," I think we should make this a duplicate of your more detailed question--your goal in each seems to be the same.