# Sequence of scripts sourced upon login

Tags: bash, login, bashrc, .profile

I would like to concentrate all my login config in my `~/.bash_profile`.  There was a `~/.bashrc` there by default but I replaced it with a `~/.bash_profile`.

However, when I log in, something before my `~/.bash_profile` gets sourced and displays the following:

```
Linux ubnt10-dev1 2.6.32-38-server #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:26:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Welcome to the Ubuntu Server!
 * Documentation:  http://www.ubuntu.com/server/doc

  System information as of Fri May  9 12:17:39 EDT 2014

  System load:  0.01              Processes:           74
  Usage of /:   5.5% of 18.58GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 4%                IP address for eth0: 123.x.x.x
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

New release 'precise' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Fri May  9 12:11:52 2014 from 123.x.x.x
```

I would like to remove that so that only my own splash greeting defined in my `~/.bash_profile` gets displays but I am not sure about the logic/sequence of scripts sourced/executed when a user logs in.  Can you enlighten me?

As a bonus, I would also like to know the sequence of automated sourcings/execs when the system starts, not just when a user starts a session by logging in, albeit this is a concern of lesser importance to me right now.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is kind of complex. First of all, the details depend on what kind of shell you are running. To [plagiarize myself](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695):

- When you open a terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal` for example), you are executing what is known as an *interactive, non-login* shell.
- When you log into your machine from the command line, or run a command such as `su - username`, you are running an *interactive login* shell.
- When you log in graphically, you are running something completely different. The details will depend on your system and graphical environment but in general, it is the *graphical shell* that deals with your login. While many graphical shells (including the Ubuntu default) will read `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` not all of them do.
- Finally, when you run a shell script, it is run in a *non-interactive, non-login shell*.

The files that bash will read when launched depend on the type of shell it is running as. The following is an excerpt of the INVOCATION section of `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> When  bash is invoked as an **interactive login shell**, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  commands  from  the file **/etc/profile**, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for **~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>    in  that order**, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>   exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
>    shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When an **interactive shell** that is **not a login shell**  is  started,  bash
>   reads  and  executes  commands  from **/etc/bash.bashrc** and **~/.bashrc**, if
>   these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using the  --norc  option.
>   The  --rcfile  file option will force bash to read and execute commands
>   from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

Those are the initialization files. You also have `/etc/environment` where you can set global environmental variables but that's read rather than sourced (commands inside it are not executed but variable definitions are set).

Now, the greeting you see is something else again. That is set in `/etc/motd` and is displayed through `pam_motd`. As explained in `man motd`:

> The contents of /etc/motd are displayed by pam_motd(8) after a
>   successful login but just before it executes the login shell.
>
> The abbreviation "motd" stands for "message of the day", and this 
>   file    has  been  traditionally  used  for exactly that (it requires
>   much less    disk space than mail to all users).
>
> On Debian GNU/Linux, the content  of  /run/motd.dynamic  is  also 
>   displayed.  This file is generated by /etc/init.d/motd at boot.

To remove the message just empty the `/etc/motd` file and make sure that nothing is being generated by `/etc/init.d/motd` if present.

---

Anyway, based on the output you show, you seem to be logging in via `ssh` which means you're running an **interactive login shell**, see above for what that means. 
So, in summary, the things you care about that are sourced when you log in are (and in this order):

1. The SSH daemon, via the `pam_motd` module of the PAM library, displays the contents of `/etc/motd`. Via the `pam_env` module, it sets the environment variables from `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment`.
2. A login shell is started, and the following files are read in order:

   1. `/etc/profile`
   2. `/etc/bash.bashrc` (the default Ubuntu `/etc/profile` sources `/etc/bash.bashrc`).
   3. `~/.bash_profile`. The other files that could have been read here (`~/.profile` and `~/.bash_login`) are ignored because `~/.bash_profile` exists.

Comment: A nice trick to self-discover this things is putting sentinel variables around. I mean, I put `export SET_IN_ETC_PROFILE=yes` in `/etc/profile`, `export SET_IN_HOME_ZSHRC=yes` in `~/.zhshrc` (I am a zsh user), etc... Then reboot and a nice `env|grep SET_IN` will tell you all the story. To see which variables are seen by the desktop applications (the ones you launch from the dash or the WM, without using a terminal), see http://askubuntu.com/a/356973/16395

Comment: so when you ssh, that would be an interactive shell, correct?

Comment: @amphibient an interactive login shell, yes. When you open a terminal on tour local machine, it's an interactive, non login shell.

Comment: @Rmano I upvoted your comments. But moments later found the order in `env` has no relationship with the order of execution.

Comment: @xiaobai of course not, the point is that `SET_IN` will show you which files have been read, not in which order they have been read. The order is standard, it is what is shown in the man page excerpts I have in my answer.

Comment: Plus the files in `/etc/profile.d` seem to be sourced in "sorted as usual" order (256.., a..., b..., x....). Good to have if you want a specific fragment to be executed last.

Comment: @Rmano an alternative to this that also preserves order is to create a `SET_IN` variable in the same manner you add to `PATH`. In each file, `export SET_IN="$SET_IN:$BASH_SOURCE"`. This will result in a variable `SET_IN` that contains all files in the order they were sourced.

Answer (score 2):

The info you are seeing when you login via ssh is created before /etc/profile is ever even looked at.  Take a look at the sequence of files in /etc/update-motd.d.  That will show you where the messages you are seeing are generated by various scripts.

Comment: This is already covered in the top answer, but I appreciate your brevity. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, `/etc/issue` is sourced before login, as described in `man 5 issue`.