# Protection For rm

Tags: server, ssh, data-recovery, rm

I sometimes work with my server over ssh. I don't want to lose anything because of an accidental `rm`. Is there a way of creating a trashbin for my server? I know it sounds stupid, but I just want to know whether there's a way of recovering stuff if I accidentally delete files.

I thought about adding a new alias for `rm`, but this won't always work. I sometimes use SFTP package of Sublime, and I also can accidentally delete stuff using it.

What can I do?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can use aliases to prevent you from using 'rm' (you can even alias it to the `trash` command in the answer)

Answer (score 2):

If you add an alias to `~./bashrc` you can prevent deleting of files. You can alias the command from the answer from Timothy Duane with

```
alias rm='trash-put'
```

Alternative:

```
alias rm='mv --verbose -f --backup=numbered --target-directory ~/.Trash/'
```

will mv files to your local Trash and also create backups if there is already a file with the same name.

If you want the alias globally:  add it to `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: Does this alias affect other applications that removes files? Like, does xFTP application or xSSH application will get affected with this alias?

Comment: @user1652575 if they use `rm` it will. But you probably want to put that alias in /etc/bashrc for global usage.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *you don't want to change the behavior of `rm` globally*. That will simply break your system<sup>1</sup>. Many programs call `rm` internally so if you change how that behaves they wont' work and this can have unexpected consequences. You will have to limit yourself to protecting *yourself* from `rm`.

You can, however, add an alias to `rm`, changing its behavior, to your `~/.bashrc`. For `ssh` sessions, you would [normally](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479/85695) need to add it to your `.profile` instead but the default Ubuntu `.profile` calls `.bashrc` so that son't be necessary unless you've changed it yourself. Basically, if you don't know what I'm talking about, just use `~/.bashrc`. The `delete` command in an FTP session is something completely different and will not be affected.

So, that said, here are a few aliases you could use:

1. `rm -i` and `rm -I`

   As explained in `man rm`, these two flags protect you from inadvertently deleting files. You can use either, depending on the level of <del>annoyance</del> protection you want:

   ```
   -i     prompt before every removal

   -I     prompt once before removing  more  than  three  files,  or  when
          removing  recursively.  Less intrusive than -i, while still giv‐
          ing protection against most mistakes
   ```

   So, for example, to have `rm` prompt you before each deletion, add this line to `~/.bashrc` and ~/.profile`:

   ```
   alias rm='rm -i'
   ```
2. Install something like `trash-cli` as already suggested and then make `rm` an alias to it:

   ```
   alias rm='trash-put'
   ```

   Now, any files you delete with `rm` will be placed in `~/.local/share/Trash/files/`.
3. Use the do-it-yourself approach with `mv` as suggested by @Rinzwind.

---

<sup>1</sup> Depending on how exactly you change its behavior, it might be fine, but it might break.

Answer (score 1):

trash-cli might suit your needs

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/make-rm-move-files-to-trash-instead-of.html

Edit:

You could also make a backup of rm and then replace all occurrences of rm with a script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from sys import argv
from subprocess import Popen
args = ''
for arg in argv[1:]:
    args += arg + ' '
Popen('trash '+args, shell=True)
```

and then use

```
chmod +x rm
```

Although I have no idea how safe this really is.

Comment: Does this protect me from rm? Is this it? That simple?

Comment: I installed it myself, and you just use the command "trash filename" instead of rm filename (:

Comment: But, as I stated in my question, Sublime Text SFTP plugin does not use trash command. I want to globally edit the rm command. Is that possible?

Comment: You can write your own rm program or script. I added a simple one using Python.

Answer (score 0):

All the proposed answered will work for your command line experience. But let me chime in with my personal suggestion: **do not do that**. Never.

*Rationale:* you should know what are you doing; using `rm` thinking that there is a safety net (with an alias, a global change in the executable(1), other things) will make you grow confident and you **will** make big mistakes when the safety net for whatever reason is not present --- that can be an update, another system, or whatever.

The `rm` command is a (complex) shell around the [unlink()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) family of [system calls](http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html) --- see it as the linux kernel service that disposes of files(2). Many programs will just use the system call, completely bypassing your safety nets.

For example, the command

```
find . -name test2.aux -delete
```

will directly call unlink, as you can see by using `strace` on it:

```
strace find . -name test2.aux -delete 
...
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "test2.aux", 0)      = 0
...
```

...and I bet the SFTP server will do the same. These are out of scope to the "protection" of your alias or even the `rm` binary substitution.

Even a simple `mv`, `cp`, or `> file` can destroy a file outside your safety net.

The only safe is a good backup(3). Learn to do it often, and double check all your commands. Triple if running as root.

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) don't do that, unless the replacement command is ready to accept exactly all the flags and corner conditions that `rm` manage.

(2) much more complex than that, really.

(3) or doing that at kernel level, probably by using a filesystem that has some kind of long term memory (a [versioning filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system#Linux)). I remember working with VMS in the late '80s --- the [filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11) did remember all version of a file appending a ";1", ";2" etc at the name, at kernel level. Handy but a maintenance nightmare.