# Access terminal from login screen on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, virtual-console

I would like to open the terminal from the login screen. In previous Ubuntu releases I just used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in 18.04, nothing happens, the login screen just stays as it is. All other combinations with F-keys (<kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>) also have no effect whatsoever.

What key shortcut do I have to press to open the terminal from the login screen?

Comment: Do you mean `tty` screen?

Comment: yes! is terminal not the right word?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ok, I rephrased my question, hope it's better now.

Comment: Are you using a VM? Are your function keys actually function keys or one of those types that need to have an Fn key pressed additionally? What if you login and run `sudo chvt 5`?

Comment: @muru, I'm not using a VM. And yes, my funtion keys need the Fn key pressed additionally. However, even with Fn pressed simultaneously, nothing happens. Running `sudo chvt 5` opens the full-screen terminal.

Comment: And once you're in the TTY, do any of  Ctrl-Alt-F* work normally?

Comment: Yes, when I press Ctrl-Alt-F1, I get back to the login screen.

Comment: My question might be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031131/cannot-switch-terminal-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1 .
However, I think the current duplicate mark is not appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, another one of these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028328/how-do-i-access-console-from-gdm-wayland One of you should report a bug and help the devs fix it. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @muru I found a way to make it work: When I switch from the open-source to the proprietary NVIDIA driver, I can access tty without a problem. So apparently, it's a bug related to the open-source graphics drivers.

Comment: I have somewhat similar problem, but only with NVIDIA driver, not by nouveau: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1811402)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ubuntu 16.04 on fresh install. Later everything started working.
Try following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Run '**Software and Updates**' and reboot

I knew answer is useless after so late but may help others

Answer (score 0):

`chvt [n]`

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chvt.1.html

And while in a tty, `shift + {left,right} arrow key` to change screens.

This can also be an issue with your login manager preventing the process. For example, some Ubuntu based distributions use SDDM as the default manager and there is a bug that can prevent changing ttys. A solution would be to disable your login manager and either starting Xorg with `startx` (with the appropriate commands in `~/.xinitrc`) or `systemctl start your-login-manager`.

```
# systemctl disable sddm
# shutdown -hr now
...
login:
password:
$ startx
    or
$ sudo systemctl start sddm
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fulfills your desired answer but at least it enables accessing the terminal as this answer is valid for the time being ubuntu release.

The trick is to access a virtual terminal.
Pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F3` (again, refer to ubuntu docs for release-specific commands) spawns a `tty` session which is similar to opening terminal, moreover, the keybinding opens entirely new parallel session (non-graphical user interface). If you are the owner (superuser), you have full access to all running sessions; this becomes especially helpful in emergency cases. As you can switch back to your first session using `Ctrl+Alt+F2` or `Ctrl+Alt+F7` as [referenced here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547290/how-do-i-get-out-of-ctrl-alt-f3)

Answer (score 0):

Enable <kbd>Fn</kbd> Lock by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

A new default configuration introduced to systemd around this time no longer allocates a graphical VT at a fixed tty7. Instead, tty1 is allocated to the display manager (`gdm` in Ubuntu Desktop), and new graphical consoles are allocated on other VTs when a user logins.

Right after boot when the graphical login screen shows up, the status of VTs may look like this:

```
tty1: gdm
tty2: (unallocated)
tty3: (unallocated)
tty4: (unallocated)
tty5: (unallocated)
tty6: (unallocated)
```

Once you log in, the new session would not appear at tty1 but at tty2:

```
tty1: gdm
tty2: gnome-shell
tty3: (unallocated)
tty4: (unallocated)
tty5: (unallocated)
tty6: (unallocated)
```

You can still pull up text mode sessions by switching to an unallocated VT in the tty1-tty6 range, which would automatically start `agetty` (and in turn text mode login) on that VT. The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F*x*</kbd> from `gdm`, or simply <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F*x*</kbd> from a text console, where *x* is a number key from 1 to 6.

If you have ever started a text session on tty2 before logging in from gdm, however, the graphical session will start on tty3, since tty2 is already used for text console.

```
tty1: gdm
tty2: text console
tty3: gnome-shell
tty4: (unallocated)
tty5: (unallocated)
tty6: (unallocated)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by pressing the combination button

**Ctrl** + **alt** + **T**

Call the terminal

Comment: That's not correct actually. `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` works only from a GUI session, that is after the user logs in. What the OP wants is launch a virtual terminal before logging in. It's just that the OP is confused about the terminology (I don't blame them) that made them ask about "terminal" and has probably led you to post this answer. Related: [What's the difference between the TTY and the GNOME terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/466688/618353)

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, I just gave my opinion that it might help, I hope he can solve his problem. Currently, I have just migrated from Windows to the Linux world. I am a beginner and I am learning.