# What init files will be read when opening a new tab and a new window of gnome terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

If I am correct, I remember that opening a new tab in genome terminal will run .bashrc, and opening a new gnome terminal window also will.

Do these two read the same init files of bash?

E.g. ~/.bashrc, not ~/.bash_profile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Opening a new tab or a new terminal does exactly the same thing: it launches a new instance of your `$SHELL` (bash by default) in interactive, non-login mode. What this means is that the following files are read:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
~/.bashrc
```

If you start a login shell, bash will read `/etc/profile`, and the first of these it finds: `/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`. This is all explain in the Invocation section of `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
> non-interactive  shell with the --login option, it first reads
> and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file
> exists.   After  reading    that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile,
> ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and
> executes commands from the first one  that exists  and  is
> readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the    shell is
> started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> [...]
>
> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started,
> bash    reads and executes commands from  /etc/bash.bashrc  and
> ~/.bashrc,  if    these  files  exist.

For more details on the various files sourced or executed under different conditions, see my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479/85695).