# Unable to set JAVA_HOMEin Ubuntu with space in path in /etc/environment

Tags: command-line, bash, java, environment-variables

I am annoyed trying this but all I am trying to do is set JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment file in Bash shell on Windows which is being offered now with Windows. My local Java is at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91 so in my /etc/environment I am putting

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/"
```

Read online that to specify a space, one should use `\`. On doing this:

```
cd /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/
```

I can navigate to directory but on putting the same in /etc/environment file and sourcing it, if I run

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/
```

I can tell that it is incorrect as it is reading it as \, and which is why doing

```
cd $JAVA_HOME
```

fails

Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

If someone can please suggest as to how to solve this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try `export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/`  (note the lack of quotes)

Comment: @CharlesGreen sorry I forgot to put them in my question.. I do have them in file

Comment: @user3044240 You miss my point, which is echoed in an answer below.  Either do not escape the space, or do not use the quotes, but do not do both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a space in the Linux world you need to do one (and only one) of the following:

1. Quote all the things:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/"
   cd "$JAVA_HOME"
   ```
2. Escape the space:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/
   cd "$JAVA_HOME"
   ```

But not both. The issue here is that quoting protects the quoted string and makes it be interpreted literally. So while `foo\ bar` means `foo`, a space and then `bar`, `"foo\ bar"` means `foo`, a backslash, a space and then `bar`.

Also, whenever you use a variable, you should pretty much always put it inside double quotes otherwise the command you are passing it to will read two arguments. You can see what went wrong if you enable bash debugging by running `set -x` (run `set +x` to turn it off):

```
$ set -x
$ cd $JAVA_HOME
+ cd /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

What you ran was `cd /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/`. Since whitespace separates arguments, this means you passed `cd` two separate arguments: `/mnt/c/Program` and `Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/`. Quoting causes `cd` (or any other tool) to read the whole thing as a single argument.

Further reading:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/222222)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use export in `/etc/environment`, it's just a simple file and not a script. It is reading the lines one by one and is setting the variables that way.

Again, it will not run commands.

Comment: I did this 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/"

Comment: You should really just use ~/.profile for that.

Comment: I did this and sourced the environment file and it sets JAVA_HOME but on running java -version it fails.. I appended it to PATH as well
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/"

Comment: Argh! You're absolutely right and [I even knew that, dammit](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479/85695). Sorry, serious PEBKAC there. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you have to set a JAVA_HOME variable for the environment.

Do the following things:

1. Find the path where your java is installed. (Most likely in /usr/lib/jvm/{JAVA_VERSION}).
2. Now on the other terminal, open        sudo vi /etc/environment
3. You have to enter: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle"