# Alias config is not loaded correctly

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias

This is my alias configuration in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

```
root@Ubuntu:/# cat /etc/.bash_aliases 
alias i='ifconfig | grep eth -A 1'
alias l='ls -lh'
root@Ubuntu:/# 

root@Ubuntu:/# cat /etc/bash.bashrc
### *output truncated* ###
if [ -f /etc/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . /etc/.bash_aliases
fi
root@Ubuntu:/#
```

However, when I test it, only `alias i='ifconfig | grep eth -A 1'` is working as expected.

```
root@Ubuntu:/# i
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
root@Ubuntu:/# 

root@Ubuntu:/# alias i
alias i='ifconfig | grep eth -A 1'
root@Ubuntu:/#
```

Another alias `alias l='ls -lh'` does not work as expected.

```
root@Ubuntu:/# l
bin/   dev/  home/
root@Ubuntu:/#
```

The output should be like this:

```
root@Ubuntu:/# ls -lh
total 80K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jul 21 14:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jul 21 14:52 boot
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root 3.8K Nov  3 12:22 dev
root@Ubuntu:/#
```

It turns out that `l` does not follow my alias config.

```
root@Ubuntu:/# alias l
alias l='ls -CF'
root@Ubuntu:/#
```

I guess `alias l='ls -CF'` must be configured at somewhere else.

The question is how to find out the location of `alias l='ls -CF'` config file?

Comment: Read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files -- start with `/etc/profile`, look at all the files it sources. Then look at your own .bash_profile or .profile and look at all the files they source. Then look at your .bashrc and all the files it sources.

Comment: I'd suggest you put your own personal preferences in your ~/.bashrc and leave the /etc/... files alone.

Comment: … and don't work with the root account, but rather with a normal user.

Comment: IIRC `alias l='ls -CF'` is defined in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, which by default will get copied to all new accounts on creation (including that of `root`)

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman for your feedback.

The reason why I put this on /etc/... and not my own directory because this is a test image and I've multiple test users.

I would like to use the same alias on each test users.

Is there a way to find this alias file automatically instead of manual way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Well, you can't get around the fact that the last (re)definition of an alias will always apply; since users' preferences always take precedence your options are either to modify the default `/etc/skel/.bashrc` or (since it sources `~/.bash_aliases` if present **after** the default alias definitions) provide a suitable `~/.bash_aliases` that overrides it again.

Comment: Another option is you could just change the name of the alias to something like `lh`, so it won't get overwritten by the default `~/.bashrc`. This has an added benefit of not confusing users who expect `l` to be aliased to `ls -CF`.

Answer (score 2):

There already exists alias for `l` in `.bashrc` ( in fact, it is defined in `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and that is copied to user's home directory when user is created) and that's what's overwriting yours:

```
$ grep '^alias l=' /etc/skel/.bashrc                                                                                                                                   
alias l='ls -CF'
$ grep '^alias l=' ~/.bashrc                                                                                                                                           
alias l='ls -CF'
```

However, that's not the only force at play here. What also happens is that  `bash` sources files in [specific order](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479/295286) (and depending on the mode in which it has been started - interactive, non-interactive, remote shell, etc.). The general idea is that it goes from files defined in `/etc/` to files defined in your home directory, so your alias indeed does get defined when `bash` sources `/etc/.bash_aliases`, but then it gets re-defined when `bash` sources your `~/.bashrc`.

Here's a demo:

```bsh
$ # define alias in your file and let it source via /etc/bash.bashrc
$ echo "alias sayhi='echo hi'" | sudo tee -a /etc/.bash_aliases
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
alias sayhi='echo hi'
$ echo "[ -f  /etc/.bash_aliases ] && source /etc/.bash_aliases" |          
> sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
[ -f  /etc/.bash_aliases ] && source /etc/.bash_aliases
$ # start new interactive shell
$ bash
$ sayhi
hi
$ # Works, right ? now define same in ~/.bashrc
$ echo "alias sayhi='echo nope'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ # and start shell again, let all files source
$ bash
$ sayhi
nope
```

Note that `bash --posix` , i.e. when shell is in posix mode, the `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` apparently aren't sourced; I tested multiple times, but my alias invocation didn't produce any results in that mode.

```
$ echo "echo 'I am bashrc'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ bash
I am bashrc
$ exit
$ bash --posix
bash-4.3$
```