# Strange message at end of MOTD on login

Tags: command-line, ssh, motd

I've got a server running Ubuntu 18.04, and whenever I login through SSH I receive this at the end of my MOTD:

```
Command 'syncthing' is available in '/snap/bin/syncthing'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
syncthing: command not found
```

I do have Syncthing set up on the server (installed through `snap`), but I run it using a script that launches it in a screen session (I run this script manually, as far as I know it should not run automatically). Is there anywhere I can check to see why it might be trying to run? I've checked `.bashrc` but there isn't any entries in there. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Running the first suggestion from Terdon's comment printed nothing, and the second command printed the following:

`etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh:syncthing`

I opened that file, sure enough there was a line with just `syncthing`. I commented out that line, logged out and back in and the issue was gone.

Comment: Perhaps the motd system is trying to call it for some reason? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `grep -R syncthing /etc/update-motd.d`. Then, also post the output of `grep syncthing ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: @terdon Edited, looks like the issue is resolved. If you want to post this as a solution I can accept it, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there's something weird like this going on during shell initialization, your first step should be to examine all of the files that shells read to when starting. Since the various different types of (bash) shell [read different files](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479/85695), you can use this command to find the string `syncthing` in all possibly re;revant files:

```
grep syncthing ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \ 
               ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \ 
               /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null.
```

In your case, the offending file was one of the files in `/etc/profile.d`, so just remove or comment the relevant line out and you should be ready to go!