# Why do I need to run source command for .bashrc alias to get applied?

Tags: command-line, bash

While I understand that `source` command executes a program in the current shell, I don't quite understand why we need to run `source .bashrc` to "reload" the .bashrc file.

From my understanding, we do not run any script by adding an alias to .bashrc - with `source .bashrc` we just "reload" the file.

Why does it not reload automatically?

Probably, I'm missing something.

How does it work under the hood? Why do we need to `source` this file to get new aliases working without login out?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login

Comment: Why should it reload automatically?

Comment: In addition to the others, you may want to learn that you can use a different file for your aliases. I use .bash_aliases, for example. I sometimes want to do different things with my aliases, so I also have a .bash_aliases2 and load that one as the source when I want to use that aliases profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.bashrc` is read only once, when bash starts. It is just so by design (and has always been). If you make any subsequent changes to `.bashrc`, they won't be applied until `.bashrc` is re-read. By running `source .bashrc`, you make exactly this - you tell bash to re-read that file.

Of course you can also start a new copy of bash (by eg. starting a new terminal session), this will cause the new bash process read the `.bashrc` file again (but there will be no changes in the old session).

BTW. `.bashrc` file **is** a script, and by sourcing it, you execute the commands placed in that file. The commands define aliases in your case, but there can be virtually any commands placed in that file.

Comment: you could also use *exec bash* to replace the  current bash process with a new.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this would need to be root as the root user. Type `sudo -s` then run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @bikerben Only if you want to change `.bashrc` file for root. If you want to change your own `.bashrc` file, there is no need to become root to reload it.

Comment: I suppose I should mention I needed to do this when using WSL. The method above didn't work otherwise.

Comment: Regardless of WSL or not, root privileges should not be needed to reload `.bashrc` of a non-root user.