# Where to Source your .Profile (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: bash, bashrc, 21.10, .profile

Recent instructional video I was watching said to put your export PATH="$PATH..." statement in your .profile and after sourcing manually in the terminal to append ". ~/.profile" to your .bashrc file as well.  However, when I do this it messes up my terminal when I open a new tab rather than allows me to access the bin from the path.

Did this behavior change?  If so, where is the correct place to source my profile so that opening a new tab or terminal window gives access to the same commands/executables in the bin folder I am referencing?

Mainly need guidance on ensuring that changes to .profile did not need to be referenced elsewhere.  This was understood and picked up by the person who answered my question - marked as answer below.

Edited for clarity and to fix a typo.

Comment: New _table_, did you mean _tab_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has a non-standard setup it has inherited from Debian and its `.bashrc` file is sourced by `.profile`:

```
$ grep -A1 bashrc /etc/skel/.profile 
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
```

So if you then also source `.profile` from `~/.bashrc` you get into an infinite loop, which will break your shell.

The right way to add a new directory to your `$PATH` is to edit `~/.profile`. The file is sourced every time you start a new login shell and, on Ubuntu systems, is also sourced when you log in graphically. After modifying `~/.profile` to add something to the `$PATH`, the change will take effect next time you log in. So instead of making `~/.bashrc` source `~/.profile`, just logout and log back in again and your changes will be there.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: nowhere. `.profile` is sourced automatically each time you log in. `.bashrc` is sourced each time an interactive terminal starts. There is no use in trying to source `.profile` once more in `.bashrc`, which actually causes an infinite loop on Ubuntu because `.bashrc` is sourced in `.profile`.

So far with respect to the problem you ask about, problem *Y*.

With respect to your real problem, *X*, i.e., having a `bin` folder in your `PATH`: no other action is needed than 1) creating `~/bin` (and/or `~/.local/bin`), then 2) log out and back in. If these directories exist, they are automatically added to your PATH (you can see the code that does that in `~/.profile`). To keep things neat, do not add other directories to your PATH, although you could do so in your `.profile` file.

Answer (score -1):

`export PATH=$PATH':<path>:<another path>'` appends paths to the PATH environment variable. It is the paths that should be used when locating executable files (programs).

If you have a program in `/home/<user>/bin` called 'Gloop', and you type `Gloop` at the command prompt in the bash shell (terminal), it normally won't execute, because `/home/<user>/bin` is not in the `PATH` variable, so bash doesn't know to look there for programs names.

So, you would go up to the first line, and insert `/home/<user>/bin` with your actual username, in place of `<path>`, and then you can type `Gloop` at the command line, and it will launch.

But sometimes you want to execute a program, but you don't want it in the PATH.

Then, you do `./Gloop` from the directory the program is in. Why you would want to append the contents of .Profile to the PATH is beyond me. It's usually empty, so the effect would be nothing!

If you want to make your changes to the PATH environment variable persistent across reboots, put the `export` command, and everything else you need from the first line of this answer, and append it to the end of the file `/home/<user>/.bashrc`

`.bashrc` holds your personal bash environment. It is `sourced` each time you log in. Try taking another look at the video, and see what the author is trying to do with `.Profile`

Comment: `/home/<user>/bin` is a bad example: Ubuntu is set up to automatically include such directory in the PATH during login if it exists (see a default `.profile` to see how this works).

Comment: Yes, `$USER/bin` is added to the `$PATH` automatically on Ubuntu. And `.profile` is _not_ empty by default! `.bashrc` is not sourced when you log in, it is sourced when you open a new interactive, non-login shell. Login shells do not source it by default, they source `~/.profile` (and some other files) instead. It just happens that Ubuntu's deafult `.profile` _also_ sources `~/.bashrc`. See [Sequence of scripts sourced upon login](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479) for more details.

Comment: I'm not used to operating systems that tuck me into bed and kiss me goodnight. Aside from the nit picking and hair splitting, you can get the general idea. We're not in second grade anymore! .Profile is normally empty. It might not be the current fashion in Ubtuntu, but these fashions come and go. .Plan and .Profile are for use by the user! It's idiotic to use them for that. And, Linux normally sources  the bash environment when it finds who you are, at login! How else are you supposed to do anything with the shel!? You might want to check on those things.

Comment: Or are you talking about GUI greeter login?

Comment: Could someone just delete my long comment. I guess I can't do that.