# How do I get rid of /sys/kernel/debug/tracing?

Tags: 16.04, mount, debug

I have two Ubuntu 16.04.1 servers providing DHCP and DNS services on my network. Today, on one of my servers, I discovered a new filesystem mounted at `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing`. The other server, which is configured almost identically, does not have this filesystem mounted.

Why did this filesystem get mounted? How do I get rid of it?

```
> uname -a
Linux net-services-02 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic root=/dev/mapper/net--services--02--vg-root ro

> cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# [... more comments ...]
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/net--services--02--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=363b849e-4574-410a-acf9-e84c95d7d879 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/net--services--02--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the output of 'cat /proc/cmdline'?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Okay.

Comment: can you update your question with the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought the problem had something to do with your `Linux net-services` revealed by `uname -a` command. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop so had little hope I could solve these two questions. I read up on the situation from this link: ([redhat.com - Realtime Tuning Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Tuning_Guide/sect-Realtime_Tuning_Guide-Realtime_Specific_Tuning-Using_the_ftrace_Utility_for_Tracing_Latencies.html)) that discusses `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/`

### Question 1: How did "debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug" get mounted?

Imagine my surprise learning on my system kernel tracing was also enabled:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/ftrace_enabled
1
```

Also when I type `mount`, this is one of the lines that appears:

```
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
```

I rebooted my kernel `4.4.0-47` to `4.4.0-45` then to `4.8.5` and finally to `3.13.0-92`. **ALL** these versions have `/sys/kernel/debug` mounted.

To answer your question (paraphrased) "how did this happen?" -> it happens to everyone.

### Question 2: How do I get rid of it?

To answer your question "how do I get rid of it?", use:

```
sudo umount debugfs
```

Note this only works for current session.

### Summary Thoughts

Even though trace is **enabled** on all Ubuntu kernel versions I've tested, it is **not activated** until you tell it to start monitoring a specific event. After an event is activated then it will slow down your CPU.

Basically I would not worry about this...