# What are the implications of disabling debugfs for ubuntu

Tags: mount

Within my mounted partitions the [`debugfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugfs) is mounted.

```
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
```

What does Ubuntu use the `debugfs` for: any userland functions, or crash reporting? I understand the linux kernel default uses, and how to disable, and unmount `debugfs`. What are the implications of disabling `debugfs` for ubuntu, rather than general `debugfs` information not pertaining to ubuntu?

Comment: Start here https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2011-January/013418.html

Comment: "Any driver that uses debugfs would not be loadable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/429321/) in addition to the link you just posted. I believe it simply means if there are issues in your file system you won't trace logs since it would be disabled. But of course you can weigh the pros and cons from there.

From `man debugfs`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       The debugfs program is an interactive file system debugger. It  can  be
       used  to  examine  and  change the state of an ext2, ext3, or ext4 file
       system.
```

From there you can see what `debugfs` you need it to run checks on your mounted fs, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880841/is-is-possible-to-use-ftrace-without-debugfs) it states "Technically it's not possible to select function_trace without debugfs enabled", so as mentioned above, again look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847962/how-do-i-get-rid-of-sys-kernel-debug-tracing) for ubuntu specific information but I think it's general any way.

Comment: This is general information on debugfs, I was wondering about ubuntu specific uses.